# How to: 301 Redirect /category/ to /customname/

Tags: categories, redirect, htaccess

I've changed our "category base" in WP settings from the default "category" to "customname".

Now there are 404 errors to links containing the old category slug eg. mysite.com/category/names

What do I enter in .htaccss to 301 redirect

mysite.com/**category**/xxx

to

mysite.com/**customname**/xxx

Thanks,

Answer (score 13):

Htaccess is your friend in this case.
You can create 301 form your old category base to the new like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^old_dir/(.*) http://www.example.com/new_dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Change old_dir to category example.com to your domain and new_dir to your custom name.

Hope this helps.
Ohad.

Comment: this almost works. It redirects "everything" to: 
**example.com/new_dir**

So for example **http://www.example.com/old_dir/news/**

is redirected to

**http://www.example.com/new_dir/**

but instead it should redirect to 

**http://www.example.com/new_dir/news**

What should be changed? thx

Comment: yep' my bad i updated the code.

Comment: yea nice edit lol! you win buddy. cheers

Answer (score 0):

> > RewriteEngine on RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^old_dir/(.*) http://www.example.com/new_dir/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> This is working fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Ok by Googling (which I was doing for hours before posting here) I found the answer! But this time I googled the beginning part of your suggested rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^olddir/
```

which resulted in finding the answer [here](http://www.andrefredette.com/blog/?p=23) which is:

```
RewriteRule ^olddir/?(.*)$ newdir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

hope this helps someone else. Now just need to find the rewrite rule for:
[How to? Redirect /category/sci-fi/ to /category/scifi/?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8669/how-to-redirect-category-sci-fi-to-category-scifi)

thx

Comment: the same way.  RewriteRule ^sci-fi/?(.*)$ scifi/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Why did you vote down my answer?

No it's not the same way because the URL is site.com/category/scifi NOT site.com/scifi.

Comment: what???? whats  RewriteRule ^sci-fi/?(.*)$ scifi/$1 [R=301,L]   got to do withthe vote down? its for the answer with the same code as mine 3 minutes after i posted it. sorry but if you feel that bad edit your answer and i'll remove the vote

Comment: I'm only trying to help you buddy.

Comment: The code you posted dumped everything to ONE absolute location. Thus why I searched and found the correct code that changes the /dir/ page of the url ONLY and so posted I it and source. Thus, I see no reason to vote down my answer when the code I posted does something different.

Comment: nice edit. Thanks for you "help" aka down vote.

Comment: What? Dude you asked a question, i answers, you commented,i edited my answer an then you found the same answer and posted it. There is a time stamp on every post and edit.