# How to redirect all pages of a blog to a new blog

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have two wordpress blogs integrated with two different websites. Both websites have the following structure.

```
www.mysite.com
-root
  -index.html
  -about.html
  -blog (folder which contains wordpress blog)

 www.mynewsite.com
    -root
      -index.html
      -about.html
      -blog (folder which contains wordpress blog)
```

I have exported all the blog posts and pages from www.mysite.com to the blog of www.mynewsite.com, and now I want to do 301 redirect to all the pages/post of blog of www.mysite.com to blog of www.mynewsite.com.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking but did you see the following post:

[How to: 301 Redirect /category/ to /customname/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8665/how-to-301-redirect-category-to-customname)